# Golang goose migration commands with credentials from .env file

Tags: go, environment-variables, migration

I'm using `Goose` to manage my `Go` project migrations. How can I get the `connection-string` from a `.env` file?

```bash
goose -dir <migration-directory> mysql "<user>:<password>@tcp(<host>:<port>)/<database-name>" up
```

Answer (score 0):

In my .env file I set the following variables:

- GOOSE_DRIVER
- GOOSE_DBSTRING

Then I use the following shell script:

```
#! /bin/sh

set -a
. .env
set +a

goose -dir <path to migrations> "$@"
```

Then I run that instead of the goose command so that I don't have to include any configuration e.g.:

```
./goose.sh up
```